# Using a CountDownTimer and Queue together

Tags: java, android, queue, countdowntimer

I am working on a "Simon Says" pattern game. The player must repeat an increasingly long pattern till they mess up.
The game consists of a 2x2 grid of colors, each with a darker one behind it. By changing the alpha from 1--->0---->1. I give the effect of clicking.

Below is the code I am using to display the pattern as it increases, it's called whenever the pattern resets or increases. But currently it always skips the last value in the pattern, and if the same color is repeated it does not flash again, it simply remains dark, what am I doing wrong?

Helpful Information:

- Pattern is the arraylist where I am storing the pattern the user must repeat.
- getColorById returns the corresponding ImageView for each color [0-3]

TLDR:

- I need to flash every single item in an arrayList called pattern, so the player can see it and repeat it, yet currently it skips the last item and if the same item is repeated it simply stays flashed versus flashing twice.

EDIT: Sometimes, the last item in the sequence does show, but it is very random on whether it shows or not.

```html
    public void flashPattern(View view){
    final Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>(pattern);
    final int timeBetweenSteps = 500;
    new CountDownTimer(pattern.size() * timeBetweenSteps, timeBetweenSteps) {
        private ImageView lastLight = null;

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            if (lastLight != null) {
                lastLight.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(250);
            }
            lastLight = getColorById(queue.remove());
            lastLight.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(250);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            if (lastLight != null) {
                lastLight.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(250);
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```